# Using jQuery "this" plus a CSS selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I am writing a script to show/hide a section within a div. I have 3 of these divs with hidden sections but was hoping to use one function to control all 3.

Here's what I have right now:

```
$('.rates, .hours, .otherinfo').click(function() {
    $('.expand').toggle();
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="rates">
    <h2>Rates</h2>
    <div class="expand">
        <p>Text in here is hidden by default.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hours">
    <h2>Hours</h2>
    <div class="expand">
        <p>Text in here is hidden by default.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="otherinfo">
    <h2>Other Info</h2>
    <div class="expand">
        <p>Text in here is hidden by default.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.expand {
    display:none;
}
```

Obviously, this shows the "expand" div for all 3 of the divs when you click on any of them. Is there a way to incorporate `this` into the selector. Something like `this'.expand'`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to expand only the element that got clicked?

Comment: Give it some context.  Show the corresponding HTML markup please.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user3388636 response worked for me, but I'll add the HTML for others' reference. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thank-you.  "for others' reference" is really the point of SO.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$(this).find('.expand').toggle()`

Comment: $(".expand", this) for short

Answer (score 2):

You should add a fiddle for better answer. But something like this should work.

```
$("#something").click(function(){$(this).children("section").toggle();});
```